# Is it possible to hide a div when a page is opened from a link, rather than navigated to?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want a situation where if I supply a  link to a page and a viewer clicks it, a single  element (breadcrumbs) is hidden on that page, but if that person navigates to the page on their own that same  element (breadcrumbs) is displayed.

Is there a fast and dirty way to accomplish this?

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind is to pass an argument in the querystring.

Comment: Of course, either query params on the url or cookies would be my suggestion.

Comment: You can check the referer to see if they came from a link or by entering the URL directly.

Comment: Use a variable in the URL based on the referrer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes,

In the link provide a query paramater something like: &clickedFromLink=true

Then using whatever language you use or javascript, check if this property exists in the URL on the page you have breadcrumb and make changes accordingly.

When someone just typed in the URL, they will not have the URL parameter.

Cheers